# Attaching plain text file using MFMailComposer in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've been trying to use MFMailComposer to send a text file with encrypted data within. The problem is my attachment never shows up when when the email arrives in the inbox. Instead, a line of "`<br/><br/>`" is always present. I'm assuming is has something to do with the mime type and the receivers mail server not know how to read the data but I just can't figure out a solution.

Anyone come across this before and have a solution?

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
   MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mailController.mailComposeDelegate =self;
   [mailController setSubject:@"Records"];
   [mailController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
   [mailController addAttachmentData:dataToBeEncrypted mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"Records.txt"];
   [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
   [mailController release];
  } else {
  //Pop up a notification
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not send email. Verify Internet conneciton and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
  }
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I got a fix. I just took a shot in the dark after seeing another example and it seemed to work. For mimetype, I just put @"mime".

I'm a little weary of it, so I'll have to do some more testing to make sure the file always comes out correct.